# App size appears bigger on the Play Store than reported in the Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app that is reported as 11.2 MB - 15.4 MB on the Google Play Console. The app has been out for a few months that is the size I see on the Play Store as well when I install the app. I just published an update for the app for internal testing on Closed Track and the app size is reported as the same (11.2 MB - 15.4 MB) on the Google Play Console but when I installed the update, the update appeared to be 23 MB. I don't know why did the app size increase all of a sudden on Google Play Store when it is reported as 11.2 MB - 15.4 MB on the Google Play Console.

I downloaded the app bundle from the Play Console and used `bundletool` to generate the APKs and they are also in the same range of 11.2 MB - 15.4 MB.

Please share if you have any information regarding this behavior and/or possible solutions.

Comment: The compression of the app can have a slight delay. Have you tried again after an hour or so? Also, are you publishing on an [internal testing track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) or using [internal app sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479)?

Comment: @Pierre The app is published on the Closed Track which used to be called Alpha Testing Channel earlier. It has been a few hours since the app is available on the Play Store and it is still reported as 23 MB.

Comment: Could you please reach out to the [Play Developer support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994). We can investigate if we have the package name. Provide them with a link to this post so we can find it more easily.

Comment: @Pierre Thanks. I have sent an email to the Play Developer support team with this information.